# Why are the DOM plain html elements rendered only after my Angular APP is done loading?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display a plain html/css loading spinner on first load in my Angular APP. The spinner code is included in my index.html.

However, the dom seems not to be rendered until my angularjs APP starts kicking in, causing a very lengthy display of a white screen until this finally happens. Is there any way to prevent that?

I would like to understand how to load my plain html/css spinner right after the css code in the head is done loading so as to improve user experience.

Test on webpagetest.org seem to confirm this diagnosis (the /settings, /introductions, /menus lines are all calls to an external API done by an AngularJS service before render):

[image: webpagetest.org diagnosis]

Here is a simplified version of my build code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <title ng-bind="($title || 'Home') + ' - WalktheChat'">WalktheChat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lib.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="base-container" ng-controller="Shell as main">
        <div ng-include="'app/layout/header.html'"></div>
        <div id="content" ui-view ng-cloak autoscroll="true"></div>
        <div ng-include="'app/layout/footer.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- This is the spinner I would like to display on first load -->
    <div ng-show="::false" class="spinner-container">
        <div class="spinner sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/lib.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use ng-show or ng-hide

Comment: can you show your app.js

Comment: I would love to, but the app is quite complex, it has a modular structure with many components, so there is not really a single "app.js". There are many files and separate applications for every sub-module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was coming from "render-blocking javascript", I had to add the "async" tag to my JS to fix it.

When adding async to both my lib.js and app.js, I had an issue with app.js loading before angular scripts were loaded (thus causing the APP to throw an error). In order to solve this issue, I combined my lib.js and app.js into one single file and then added the async tag.

My final build code looks like that (the magic happens on the final "script" tag):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <title ng-bind="($title || 'Home') + ' - WalktheChat'">WalktheChat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lib.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="base-container" ng-controller="Shell as main">
        <div ng-include="'app/layout/header.html'"></div>
        <div id="content" ui-view ng-cloak autoscroll="true"></div>
        <div ng-include="'app/layout/footer.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- This is the spinner I would like to display on first load -->
    <div ng-show="::false" class="spinner-container">
        <div class="spinner sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- This app.js now also contains lib.js from my question !-->
    <script src="js/app.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever the complexity of your application,all your controllers are within the same angular application, all scopes within the same application inherits from the same root, whatever you define on the $rootScope will be available to all child scopes.

we have two ways to resolve this problem:

1. use $broadcast(), $emit() and $on() that facilitate event driven publisher-subscriber model for sending notifications and passing data between your controllers.(professional solution)
2. declare $rootScope variable and watching changement.(simple way)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not sure it is addressing the question. My problem is not to propagate changes or variables through my application. What I would like is display a plain html/spinner before my app.js / angular.js / etc... are even downloaded. I would like this to happen right away while my libs/app are downloading. What I don't understand is: why isn't the plain html displayed properly while my APP is loading (before Angular is here is here to tell what should or shouldn't be displayed)

Comment: Way not integrate your plan html/spinner in custom directive

Comment: I also have a spinner in a directive which works well for all my other HTTP requests. In this case, what I want is the spinner **not** to be in a directive as I want to to be displayed before AngularJS actually started bootstrapping. My concern, is that the DOM is actually rendered only after AngularJS start bootstrapping, thus keeping this initial spinner from being displayed.

Comment: Why not using timeout

Comment: I don't believe angular functions can help me because I am trying to have this spinner display before angular actually got loaded.